# Request Failed with 400 | Gatling 2.2.5

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I am using Gatling tool for my load testing of API. I thought of isolating process into Objects. But when i run my scenario i get the below error:

```
Simulation testapi.AdvancedSimulationStep05 started...
14:12:50.981 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'PostMultiline' failed: status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209), but actually found 400
14:12:50.981 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'PostMultiline' failed: status.find.in(200,304,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209), but actually found 400
```

Below is my Scala Simulation code:

```
class AdvancedSimulationStep05 extends Simulation {

  object Search {

    val search = exec(
            http("PostMultiline")
            .post("/t_rates/v1/quotations")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(RawFileBody("test.json")).asJSON
        )
  }

  val httpConf = http
    .baseURL("https://central-us.rates")
    .acceptHeader("application/json, */*")
    .acceptCharsetHeader("UTF-8")

  val users = scenario("Users").exec(Search.search)
  val admins = scenario("Admins").exec(Search.search)

  setUp(
    users.inject(rampUsers(10) over (10 seconds)),
    admins.inject(rampUsers(2) over (10 seconds))
  ).protocols(httpConf)
}
```

I tried several combination of running the simulation, but i still get the error. It would be great if i get some advice from the experts.

Comment: Did you try such request manually? I mean using tool like *postman*?

Comment: Yes @Eugene , i tried with Postman... the URL is working

Comment: Can your server handle the load generated by Gatling?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes it can. I have tested the same by giving JSON using the String body method 
```.body(StringBody("""{"date": "2017-06-07","company": "test","division": "1002"}""")```

Comment: Do you have some public URI that we may to try from outside?

Comment: @Eugene I am sorry ... i don't have a public URI